# Lightning component tab title stuck in "Loading"

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a Lightning Component Tab I access at a URL such as:

`/lightning/n/MyComponent?c__recordId=myrecordid`

The tab loads fine and there are no Javascript errors. However the tab title stays in the "Loading" state with a loading spinner:

[image]

I do get this nonsense warning on load, if it's relevant:

> aura_proddebug.js:58979 WARNING: "pageReference" must either be a public property of cMyComponent or a global HTML attribute

I'm not sure what else to debug here.

Comment: lol @ closing when this is a known bug. good job everyone!

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: [Workspace API for LWC](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_workspaceAPI.htm&release=246&type=5) was made beta in Winter '24 so you should now be able to update the title of the tab to not be "loading" with `setTabLabel` in your LWC similar to how it was done in Aura, noted below.

---

*Old Answer*

Unfortunately, this is expected behavior if you're using a Lightning Web Component (LWC) tab and greatly reduces the value of using it on its own in a console context

The issue comes down to the fact that the [workspaceAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation) is not available for LWC, only aura.

In aura, since you can leverage the workspaceAPI, you can set the label and icon of the tab:

```
<!-- in component file -->
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />

...

<!-- in controller/helper -->

let workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function (response) {
    let focusedTabId = response.tabId;
    workspaceAPI
        .setTabLabel({
            tabId: focusedTabId,
            label: "LabelTest"
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                icon: "standard:apps",
            });
        })
});
```

This means that you have to wrap your LWC within aura to allow it to set the label and display the LWC.

There's ideas for this parity gap to no longer exist

- [lightning-tab-label-showing-loading-in-service-console-LWC](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000UIgFQAW)
- [Create Lightning Web Component (LWC) versions of Aura Workspace APIs (Console)](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015AyiQAE)
- [Create Lightning Web Cmp (LWC) versions of Aura Navigation Item APIs (Console)](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015AysQAE)

There was a comment from the product manager, at the time, in one of the ideas that suggested this feature was pushed back and suggested a safe harbor timeline - however, it is still not here or coming with Winter '22.

> To offer some transparency into our product development process, **the
> LWC workspace API was almost complete in the Summer '20 release but
> then we realized there were potential negative long-term implications
> to the API design we had chosen**. We want to ensure an intuitive and
> extensible API design that feels "LWC native" and not simply a port of
> the Aura APIs. So we're back to the drawing board.
>
> We're going to give the console workspace API another shot for the
> Winter '21 release (October 2020) #safeharbor.

I've also seen the following [demonstrated (solution #2)](https://mtr-design.com/news/salesforce-mini-how-to-open-a-subtab-in-console-from-lightning-web-component) where they send a custom event to the window that replicates the same payload that seemed to work and avoid the aura necessity - though, I haven't tested/used this myself so I can't vouch for it. Example is from the site and uses `openSubTab` but I believe the same could be used for the methods I showed above.

```
this.invokeWorkspaceAPI('openSubtab', {
    parentTabId: focusedTab.tabId,
    recordId: this.accountId,
    focus: true
})
.then(tabId => {
    console.log("Solution #2 - SubTab ID: ", tabId);
});

invokeWorkspaceAPI(methodName, methodArgs) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const apiEvent = new CustomEvent("internalapievent", {
       bubbles: true,
       composed: true,
       cancelable: false,
       detail: {
         category: "workspaceAPI",
         methodName: methodName,
         methodArgs: methodArgs,
         callback: (err, response) => {
           if (err) {
               return reject(err);
           } else {
               return resolve(response);
           }
         }
       }
     });

     window.dispatchEvent(apiEvent);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this, I was able to get this to work, I'm going to add the code I'm using as a separate answer

Answer (score 3):

The other answer explains the bug in Lightning Component Tabs. I was able to set the tab title and tab icon in an LWC using the following setup

### Utility class mixin

```js
/**
 * Compare two page references to see if they're equal by looking at API name
 * and URL (which is in state.ws). Page refences are (apparently) unique every
 * time you get a reference to one, so we can't check "===" equality
 */
const arePageRefsEqual = (p1, p2) =>
  p1.attributes.apiName === p2.attributes.apiName && p1.state.ws === p2.state.ws;

const LwcWorkspaceApi = Base =>
  class extends Base {
    /**
     * The Workspace API has a method called "getEnclosingTabId" which is
     * only available to Aura, not LWCs. Instead, search all current tabs
     * (including subtabs) for the tab which has a pageReference that matches
     * the one passed in
     */
    getEnclosingTabId = async currentPageRef => {
      const allTabs = await this.invokeWorkspaceAPI('getAllTabInfo');

      const enclosingTab = allTabs
        .flatMap(t => [t, ...t.subtabs])
        .find(t => arePageRefsEqual(t.pageReference, currentPageRef));

      console.log('enclosing tab', enclosingTab);
      if (!enclosingTab) {
        console.error('Could not find tab for pageReference', currentPageRef, 'looked in', allTabs);
        throw new Error(`Could not find tab for pageReference to set label "${label}"`);
      }

      return enclosingTab.tabId;
    };

    /**
     * Set a tab label and icon
     */
    setTabLabel = async (tabId, label, icon) => {
      console.log('setting tab label it', tabId);
      await this.invokeWorkspaceAPI('setTabLabel', { tabId, label });
      await this.invokeWorkspaceAPI('setTabIcon', {
        tabId: tabId,
        icon: icon,
        iconAlt: 'Tab Icon',
      });
    };

    isSubTab = async tabId => this.invokeWorkspaceAPI('isSubtab', { tabId });

    /**
     * Mimick calling the workspace API using the undocumented
     * "internalapievent"
     */
    invokeWorkspaceAPI = async (methodName, methodArgs = {}) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const apiEvent = new CustomEvent('internalapievent', {
          bubbles: true,
          composed: true,
          cancelable: false,
          detail: {
            category: 'workspaceAPI',
            methodName: methodName,
            methodArgs: methodArgs,
            callback: (err, response) => {
              if (err) {
                return reject(err);
              }
              return resolve(response);
            },
          },
        });

        window.dispatchEvent(apiEvent);
      });
    };
  };

export default LwcWorkspaceApi;
```

### Mixin usage in LWC

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import LwcWorkspaceApi from 'c/lwcWorkspaceApi';

export default class myComponent extends LwcWorkspaceApi(LightningElement) {
  connectedCallback() {
      const tabId = await  this.getEnclosingTabId(this.currentPageReference);
      this.setTabLabel(tabId, 'My Title', 'utility:matrix');
  }
```

This API appears to be undocumented, so it could break.